# touchableopacity react native z index

Tags: react-native, styles

I have some TouchableOpacity component that overlapping and when press one of them , It seems  decrease zindex this TouchableOpacity , how can increase zindex or other  solution for show pressed  TouchableOpacity on top ?

```html
 <View style={modalStyle.row}>
                        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} style={[modalStyle.btnText, { backgroundColor: Colors.title }]}>
                            <Text style={ { fontSize: 13,  color: '#fff'}}>30,000 </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} style={[modalStyle.btnText, { backgroundColor: Colors.title }]}>
                            <Text style={ {fontSize: 13,  color: '#fff'}}>50,000 </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} style={[modalStyle.btnText, { backgroundColor: Colors.title }]}>
                            <Text style={ { fontSize: 13, color: '#fff'}}>100,000 </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
```

```css
 btnText: {
                fontFamily: 'System', // r
                paddingHorizontal: 10,
                paddingVertical: 7,
                color: '#fff',
                position : 'relative',
                borderRadius: 25,
                textAlign: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems:'center',
                width:'35%',
            },
            row: {
                flexDirection: 'row',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'space-around',
                marginTop: 10,
                width:'85%'
                //height:100,
            }
```

[gif of my component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vaGj.gif)

Comment: What do you mean by seems to decrease zIndex? Like does it disappear?

Comment: no it's show under the others TouchableOpacity when press it @SeanWang

Comment: Could you add your `row` style and `btnText` styles?

Comment: @SeanWang have been add

Comment: Ah I see the gif, so you could use `onPressIn` and `onPressOut` events to be able to set an extra style for a modified zIndex. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#onpressin Let me know if this is unclear or you need more guidance on how to approach this solution.

Comment: @SeanWang I finally realized that the problem is not Zindex, it's a problem of opacity , and use plugin for it,this plugin creates a custom animation react-native-material-ripple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized that the problem is not Zindex, it's a problem of opacity , and use plugin for it,this plugin creates a custom animation [react-native-material-ripple](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-material-ripple)